# Rest API to get SharePoint site collection all users

Tags: rest, user-profile, site-collection

How can I get list of all users present in the SharePoint Site collection using **Rest API**.

Is that possible? Please suggest something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The REST Endpoint URI to get all the users of a Site Collection is

```
<site url>/_api/Web/SiteUsers
```